# react native run ios stuck on Implicit Dependency

Tags: ios, react-native, boost

Initially, nothing ran because of `boost` package not being able to install from `pod install` but I followed through [this issue](https://github.com/boostorg/boost/issues/843) and managed to install boost for react native.

and now, when i try to run `yarn start` with running on iOS, it gets stuck on Implicit Dependency and nothing happens.

[image]

I've been working only on Android for past few weeks with these dependencies

```
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.3.3",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.17",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "@tamagui/animations-react-native": "^1.79.19",
    "@tamagui/lucide-icons": "^1.79.19",
    "@tamagui/shorthands": "^1.79.19",
    "@tamagui/themes": "^1.79.19",
    "@tamagui/toast": "^1.79.19",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.15.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.3",
    "babel-plugin-inline-import": "^3.0.0",
    "burnt": "^0.12.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.10",
    "i18next": "^23.7.11",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.49.2",
    "react-i18next": "^14.0.0",
    "react-is": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.1",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.14.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-mmkv-storage": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^17.1.0",
    "react-native-otp-textinput": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.8.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.29.0",
    "react-native-share": "^10.0.2",
    "react-native-svg": "^14.1.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.2.1",
    "tamagui": "^1.79.19",
    "zod": "^3.22.4"
```

I've tried cleaning the project through `react-native-clean-project`, deleted the Pods. nothing seems to work.

Comment: Can you be specific? What does it mean "it gets stuck"? You took a picture (!!!?!?!) of the screen mid-process, it seems. Perhaps you can include the actual output, including any error message you may be getting? Or, at least the result that makes you say "it gets stuck"

Comment: I don't know what else to add there, that's literally about it, nothing happens after that. I thought thought there was some download process going behind the scene and I left it for an hour, its still stuck, no errors, nothing. Sorry, I'm very new to how iOS development works. I've also added `verbose` flag and all it outputs are 'Key pressed' logs, nothing else

Comment: You mean it gets stuck on the screenshot, with the cursor halfway the incomplete line starting with “-> Implicit dependency”? What is the reason you cannot include a proper text log or even a normal screenshot?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? I'm facing the same issue